# Correlation coefficient between two columns

Tags: matlab

I need correlation coefficient between two columns along with linear fit and colorbar scale.

Comment: And what have you tried yourself in order to obtain these things you want?

Comment: [Get start writing code](http://www.mathworks.in/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html).

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is your HW, so I'll come with a solution using Matlab's generic functions.

```
>> x = sin(0:0.01:20);
>> y = cos(0:0.01:20);
>> R = corrcoef(x,y)

R =

    1.0000    0.0392
    0.0392    1.0000

>> R = corrcoef(x,x)

R =

    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000
```

I think next time you may show some effort.